# Simple URL Rewrite Problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble re-writing a simple URL with .htaccess.

The URL I am trying to rewrite is:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=PAGE_NAME
```

I would like the PAGE_NAME to be directly after the domain, for example if PAGE_NAME is blog:

```
http://www.domain.com/blog
```

At the moment I have tried the following with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ index.php?page=$1
```

All help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /search.php?page=notfound

# Add WWW to URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cristianrgreco\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cristianrgreco.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove trailing slashes from end of URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.cristianrgreco\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite main page URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?page=([^\ ]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]

# Rewrite download URLs
RewriteRule ^download/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ download.php?file=$1 

# Rewrite page navigation links
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/page-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ $1.php?currentpage=$2

# Rewrite article URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$2

# Remove file extension from PHP files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#add these next 2 lines if you need to redirect http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=PAGE_NAME to http://www.domain.com/PAGE_NAME
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?page=([^\ ]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301]  

#send request to index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: i've just found one problem, now all pages get directed to index.php, for example if going from index.php to search.php, index.php will send an error saying 'page not found'

Comment: @Cristian I edited the solution a couple of times: do you have the version above? If not, can you use latest.  If yes, the `RewriteRule` above will  not match `search.php` and should not cause the result you describe. Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: i don't know how to make it, but the problem is that everything after domain.com/XXXX is being sent to index.php, how do i make it so that it's only directed to index.php if it's domain.com/?page=XXXX ?

Comment: i'm using the latest version, i have quite a few other rules I'll post them in my original post if it helps

Comment: www.domain.com/blog leads to the correct page as it is dealt with index.php, a separate file, such a register.php would be www.domain.com/register, but is dealt still with index, displaying a page not found error, if i manually type in www.domain.com/register.php it is dealt with correctly, is it a problem with the extension?

Comment: @Cristian Is `blog` the only page that should go to index.php?

Comment: no there about 15 pages, it takes the .com/?page=VAR and pulls out data for VAR in a database, this is done with index.php, other files such as register.php are also accessed from domain.com/register and .com/contact etc, but now they are sent to index which says that register is not found in the database

Comment: @Cristian Note that you are actually accessing the page via `domain.com/page_name` which then routes to index.php. If there is some pattern to the pagenames that should behave this way, or those that should be excluded then the rule could be changed, if not then there is no other way besides listing each of the 15 pages in the rule, which is not the best approach.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7477/discussion-between-ulrich-palha-and-cristian)

Comment: A MASSIVE thanks to Ulrich Palha who spent an HOUR in chat helping me fix this!